# Determine if a 2d polygon can be drawn with a single triangle fan

Tags: c++, math, geometry, computational-geometry

At first, I thought this problem would be equivalent to determining if a polygon is convex, however it seems that a non-convex polygon could still be drawn by one triangle fan.  [Consider this shape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Simple_polygon.svg), a non-convex polygon.  One could easily imagine some region of centerpoints that would allow this polygon to be drawn with a triangle fan (although there would be other centerpoints that would not).  Given a fixed centerpoint, I want to be able to determine if the set of 2d points defining the polygon allow for it to be drawn with a single triangle fan.

It seems like the key is making sure nothing "gets in the way" of a line drawn from the centerpoint to any of the vertices, that means other edge lines of vertices.  However, it is important to make this as computationally inexpensive as possible, and I'm not sure if there's a nice math shortcut to doing this.

Ultimately, I'm going to have the vertices of polygons moving, and I'll need to determine the "boundary" a vertex is allowed to move, given the rest are fixed (and perhaps later even allowing the simultaneous reactive movement of the direct 2 neighbors as well), to keep the polygon capable of being drawn in a single triangle fan.  But that's the future, hopefully the test over the full polygon can be broken into a subset of calculations to test the bounds of a single vertex's movement with the assumption of an already convex polygon.

Comment: This is an intriguing question. Perhaps one way to approach it would be to first compute the convex hull with e.g. a [Graham Scan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan). Then define whatever vertex is closest to the arithmetic mean of all the  vertices as the center vertex. And finally see if the line segment from the center vertex to any of the other vertices intersects an edge of the convex hull.

Comment: Actually, I realize the convex hull would of course give you the  wrong edges. Do you already know the edges?

Comment: If you treat each edge as a point (in homogeneous coordinates), you can use a convex hull algorithm to solve the problem.  If any of the polygon edges correspond to "negative points" within a hull formed by other edges, then you cannot draw the polygon as a triangle fan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A polygon can be drawn as a triangle fan if the angle from the anchor to each vertex moves in the same direction.  The easiest way to test this is to check the dot products of the cross products of the successive vertices.

It will look something like this:

```
vector lastCross = cross_product( vector(vertex[0] - center), vector(vertex[numVerts - 1] - center) );

canBeFan = true;
for (n = 1; canBeFan && n < numVerts; ++n) {
    vector testCross = cross_product( vector(vertex[n] - center), vector(vertex[n - 1] - center) );
    if (0.0 >= dot_product(testCross, lastCross) ) {
        canBeFan = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a test for a convex polygon?

Comment: @user173342 no, testing for a convex polygon is similar, but that is testing the difference in between the angles of each pair of edges.

Answer (score 14):

The property you're looking for is "[star-shaped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-shaped_polygon)". Star-shaped polygons are are defined by having a point from which the entire polygon is visible.

To test that a polygon is star-shaped, you can construct the region from which the whole polygon will be visible. That region would be a convex set, so you can intersect it with a halfplane in `O(log(n))`.

That means you can intersect the halfplanes formed by the edges and check that the resulting visibility region is nonempty in `O(n log n)`.

Comment: And since a fixed center point is specified you can simply make sure that that point is in all the half spaces.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like all potential centerpoints will need to be on the interior side of every edge of your polygon.  So, treat all your edges as half-spaces, and determine if their intersection is empty or not.

As @jpalecek says, the term for this is *star-shaped*.  If your polygon is star-shaped, there will be a convex polygon (interior to the original) whose points can view all edges of the original -- and, conversely, if no such sub-polygon exists, the original is not star-shaped, and you cannot draw it with a triangle fan.

Determining this sub-polygon is basically a [dual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_%28mathematics%29) application of the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) problem; it can be computed in `O(n log n)`.